# POSIX message queue - mq_send thread wake order

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, posix, ipc, message-queue

Can someone explain to me how message queues handle waking multiple
threads blocked on a single message queue?

My situation is I have multiple writers blocking on a full message
queue, each posting messages with priority equal to the thread
priority.  I want to make sure they wake and post in priority order,
however my application is behaving as if they are waking in FIFO order
(i.e. the order in which they blocked).  Each blocking thread is
scheduled with the SCHED_FIFO policy with a different priority with
system level scope.

I've searched the Internet high and low for something describing how
this should work and all I can find is POSIX man pages describing that
multiple blockers wake in priority order **if Priority Scheduling is
supported**.  Since the kernel scheduler is a priority scheduler I
would think that the threads would wake in priority order and post to
the queue, however that doesn't appear to be the case.  I'm sure I'm
just missing some subtle detail and was hoping the experts here on
this list can help shine some light on what I'm seeing, since its at
the kernel level that these threads are made ready to run.

I have a small test application that I can post here if necessary.  It simply fills a queue, then has a few threads all try and write to it, all with different thread priorities and posting with a message priority equal to the thread priority.  I then remove a message from the queue and would expect the highest priority thread wake up and post its message.  However, the first thread to wait posts its message first.

Any help or documentation anyone can point me to in order to get to the bottom of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that the priority of the created threads is what you want it to be? Normally, `pthread_create(3)` sets the priority of a new thread to inherit the priority of the creating thread, so even if you pass a new priority as the scheduling parameter when you create a thread, that value is ignored unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I've verified priorities are correct.  I set them explicitly, either in the pthread_attr_t passed to pthread_create() or by calling pthread_setschedparam() when using std::thread.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Linux kernel looks at the tasks' priority value if the queue is full and adds them to a wait queue in task niceness order (which is priority order for non-RT tasks). The wait queue does not honor real-time priorities which my application uses.  Non-RT priorities (nice values) are being handled properly and wake up in niceness order.

The root cause of my issue down in how the kernel was handling priorities when adding tasks to the internal kernel wait queues.  I submitted a patch to the linux-kernel list which was accepted and will be rolled into future releases which changes the priority check when adding tasks to the wait queue - it now honors both non-RT priority as well as RT priority.  It does NOT handle priorities of deadline scheduled tasks.